# Strings and indexes in C++

Tags: c++, string, indexing

I am learning C++ and doing some online challenges. However, it seems most of "normal" challenges I always get stuck. I'm not sure if I'm lacking of knowledge, or just overthinking it. Anyway, I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

I am trying to do this challenge:
My input is a number "N" for example, and I will have to input "N" strings afterwards.

Then I have to find the smallest amount of prefixes for each string typen and make sure they are NOT repeating.

For example, the string "stackoverflow" has many prefixes: s,st,sta,stac,stack,stacko,stackov,stackove,stackover,stackoverf,stackoverfl,stackoverflo,stackoverflow.

All these are prefixes of stackoverflow. So, if we have another string "standup", we have to type for stackoverflow - stac because there is sta in standup already, so it will be stan for standup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Erm, from my knowledge, I know that set has only UNIQUE elements if I am not mistaken. But I still am not sure what to do.

Comment: Misread the question a bit, you're right, a set is not the correct structure.

Comment: Any ideas what should I do? I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Does the word [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) ring a bell?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the expected output of "stan" and "standup"? Is that not allowed in the input or does it just ignore "stan"?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest version I can think of;

- Sort the list of words in alphabetical order. Append a copy of the second to last word to the list.
- For each word in the list, its unique prefix is the number of letters that makes it unique as compared to the next word in the list.

An example, `stackoverflow`, `standup`, `seer`.

The list becomes;

```
seer
stackoverflow
standup
stackoverflow

seer only requires `se` to be unique as compared to `stackoverflow`.
stackoverflow requires `stac` to be unique as compared to `standup`.
standup requires `stan` to be unique as compared to `stackoverflow`.
```

Done.

Comment: How do I sort the strings by alphabet order?

Comment: @user2041143 There's an example how to use `list::sort` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/).

Answer (score 0):

**Create a tree:** (trie?)

Let each node in this tree has a maximum of 26 children, one for each letter (a-z).

The path from root to leaf indicates a string.

```
        root
          \
           s
           |
           t
           |
           a
           /\
          c n
         /  |
        k   d
        |   |
        o   u
         ...
```

Just add all the items into this tree.

Then, process the tree with depth first search, whenever you get a node that only has 1 leaf in its subtree (you can keep track of these counts), print that string so far and recurse up. So at `c` and `n` there would be only 1 leaf so you'd print `stac` and `stan` respectively.

I wouldn't say the above approach is particularly well-suited for a bigger C++ programmer, but here's some code that should work: (excuse the disastrous mix of C and C++ and various other atrocities in the below, this is just a super quick-and-dirty approach)

([link](http://ideone.com/WZu6Ui))

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
  public:
    int count;
    Node *(children[26]); // array of pointers
    Node() { count = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) children[i] = NULL; };
};

void add(char *s, Node &n)
{
    if (*s == 0) // null-terminator
      return;
    if (n.children[*s-'a'] == NULL)
      n.children[*s-'a'] = new Node();
    n.count++;
    add(s+1, *n.children[*s-'a']);
}

void print(char *start, char *end, Node &n)
{
    if (n.count == 1)
    {
        *end = 0; // null-terminator
        cout << start << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (n.children[i] != NULL)
        {
            *end = (char)(i+'a');
            print(start, end+1, *n.children[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *s = "stackoverflow";
    Node root;
    add(s, root);
    s = "standup";
    add(s, root);
    char output[1000]; // big buffer
    print(output, output, root);
}
```

Comment: Interesting concept. Except this is a bit complicated. My knowledge of C++ is limited. I haven't done many challenges either, all I'm doing atm is mostly based on math, therefore after reading the article, it seems out of my level..

Comment: @user2041143 Yeah, it's probably not the easiest approach. I added some code if you want to take a look. The code may be slightly more complex than required.